# JSONArray weird Output on Different Devices

Tags: android, json

hi i have the following String

```
 [{"SUBSCRIBERID":"151-52-049","LONG":"46.69127274","LAT":"24.70912743"},{"SUBSCRIBERID":"151-29-016","LONG":46.69570000","LAT":"24.70770000"}]
```

i am converting this String to JSONArray

```
JSONArray jsonArrr = new JSONArray(String);
```

then looping the Array And getting JSONObject

```
for (int h = 0; h < jsonArrr.length(); h++) {

    jsonObj = jsonArrr.getJSONObject(h);
    Iterator<String> iter = jsonObj.keys();
    Object valuee = "";
    String key = iter.next();
    Log.e(TAG, "key is: " + key);
    try {

        valuee = jsonObj.get(key);
        Log.e(TAG, "key: " + key + "---value: " + valuee);   //on htc key is SUBSCRIBERID and its value while on samsung key is LONG and its valuee!!
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e(TAG,"SOME ERROR: "+e);
    }
```

in this for loop the value retrieved is the first value in each object.
on my HTC mobile the first value is displaying correctly as the value of SUBSCRIBERID buy on a samsung device, the first value is displaying as LONG.

please any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: try without using iterator.

Comment: i tried without an iterator and the same thing happened:/

Answer (score 2):

Order of the keys is not defined. So if you execute the code on different devices you may see keys in different orders. [REF](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys())

> Returns an iterator of the String names in this object. The returned iterator supports remove, which will remove the corresponding mapping from this object. If this object is modified after the iterator is returned, the iterator's behavior is undefined. The order of the keys is undefined.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: i don't know in advance the keys

Comment: Your keys seems to be same, you can create a POJO and map the json to that.

Comment: If keys are know in advance you can still use your code. You will get all keys and values properly, its just the order which is not same all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use without `Iterator` as mentioned in comments and above answer

```
    for (int h = 0; h < jsonArrr.length(); h++) {

      jsonObj = jsonArrr.getJSONObject(h);
//    Iterator<String> iter = jsonObj.keys();
//   Object valuee = "";
//    String key = iter.next();
//    Log.e(TAG, "key is: " + key);
//    try {  
//        valuee = jsonObj.get(key);
//        Log.e(TAG, "key: " + key + "---value: " + valuee);   //on htc key is SUBSCRIBERID and its value while on samsung key is LONG and its valuee!!
//    } catch (JSONException e) {   
//        Log.e(TAG,"SOME ERROR: "+e);
//    }      
    // use this code
    String value = jsonObj.getString("SUBSCRIBERID");
    Long lat = jsonObj.getLong("LAT");
    Long long = jsonObj.getLong("LONG");    
    Log.d("json","subscribed:"+value+",lat"+lat+",long:"+long);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     for (int h = 0; h < jsonArrr.length(); h++) 
     {     
        Log.e(TAG,"JSONObjet at "+h+" : "+jsonArrr.get(h).toString());
     }
```

try to run this